# how to increase the limit for max.print in R

Tags: r

I am using the `Graph` package in R for maxclique analysis of 5461 items.

The final output item which I get is very long, so I am getting the following warning:

> reached `getOption("max.print")` -- omitted 475569 rows

Can somebody please provide me the pointers with how to increase the limit 
for `max.print`.

Comment: you may want to find a suitable output format and export that way.  Once your data gets big enough printing to the R console rapidly becomes more of a pain than it's worth.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Use the `options` command, e.g. `options(max.print=1000000)`.

See `?options`:

```
 ‘max.print’: integer, defaulting to ‘99999’.  ‘print’ or ‘show’
      methods can make use of this option, to limit the amount of
      information that is printed, to something in the order of
      (and typically slightly less than) ‘max.print’ _entries_.
```

Comment: hello aix: see the resulting output:$maxCliques[[179798]]
[1] "n4301" "n4630" "n4480" "n4977" "n4427"

$maxCliques[[179799]]
[1] "n4301" "n4630" "n4480" "n4592"

$maxCliques[[179800]]
[1] "n4301" "n4630" "n4480" "n4328" "n4595"
... why it starts at “$maxCliques[[179798]]” instead of "$maxCliques[[1]]", so odd!

Comment: @Jeol: R prints the whole thing, but by default the console only store the last 8000 lines of output.  Go to `Edit` -> `GUI preferences...` -> `lines`, and increase the value.  Then `Save...` and `OK`.

Comment: This solution didn't work in my case - after running `options(max.print=100)` and then `head(df, 30)` I'm seeing a list of column names instead of data rows.

Answer (score 54):

See `?options`:

```
options(max.print=999999)
```

Comment: `options(max.print = .Machine$integer.max)` is the most extreme version of this

Comment: FWIW, I'm using `R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)` and need to put `max.print` in quotes.  If I don't I get the error `Error: object 'max.print' not found`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the options command to change the max.print value for the value limit you want to reach. For example:

```
options(max.print = 1000000)
```

There you can change the value of the max.print in R.

Answer (score 1):

set the function options(max.print=10000) in top of your program. since you want intialize this before it works. It is working for me.

Answer (score -4):

I fixed it just now. But it looks busty. Anyone make it simple please?

```
def list_by_tag_post(request):

# get POST
all_tag = request.POST.getlist('tag_list')

arr_query = list(all_tag)

for index in range(len(all_tag)):
    tag_result = Tag.objects.get(id=all_tag[index])

    all_english_text = tag_result.notes.all().values('english_text', 'id')

    arr_query[index] = all_english_text



for index in range(len(arr_query)):

    all_english_text = all_english_text | arr_query[index]


# Remove replicated items
all_english_text = all_english_text.order_by('id').distinct()


# render
context = {'all_english_text': all_english_text, 'all_tag': all_tag}
return render(request, 'list_by_tag.html', context)
```

Comment: is this in the right place?