# Printing loads of values in R Dataframe

Tags: r, printing

I have 7909 observations in a Dataframe. I want to record Engineer ID against a logical value (y/n) to indicate whether he arrived on site early/late:

```
> head(table(f_SOMs$ENG.ID, f_SOMs$EARLY))

                FALSE TRUE
  4PXO18            0    0
  5BZS21            0    0
  5DAD37            0    0
  6YJM50 6YGP51     0    0
  7JVE00            0    0
  7KAM01            0    0
```

The problem I have is it doesn't print the whole thing and gives this at the end of printing:

```
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 5061 rows ]
```

How to get all the values? Is there an easier way please?

Comment: Try increasing the print option with `options(max.print = 10000)`

Comment: It's unlikely you _really_ want to manually inspect that many rows. What are you trying to identify? While you can [change the max.print option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758727/how-to-increase-the-limit-for-max-print-in-r), it will probably be better to filter the output.

Comment: Trying to create a list of engineers arriving early on site.

Comment: `early_ENG.ID<-f_SOMs$ENG.ID[f_SOMs$EARLY]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to increase the limit for max.print in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758727/how-to-increase-the-limit-for-max-print-in-r)