# Why is distance matrix (dist()) giving empty values for data sets having more than ~50 observations?

Tags: r, distance-matrix

I have a data set for which I'm calculating its distance matrix. Below is the data, which has 251 observations.

```
> str(mydata)
'data.frame':   251 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ BodyFat: num  12.3 6.1 25.3 10.4 28.7 20.9 19.2 12.4 4.1 11.7 ...
 $ Weight : num  154 173 154 185 184 ...
 $ Chest  : num  93.1 93.6 95.8 101.8 97.3 ...
 $ Abdomen: num  85.2 83 87.9 86.4 100 94.4 90.7 88.5 82.5 88.6 ...
 $ Hip    : num  94.5 98.7 99.2 101.2 101.9 ...
 $ Thigh  : num  59 58.7 59.6 60.1 63.2 66 58.4 60 62.9 63.1 ...
 $ Biceps : num  32 30.5 28.8 32.4 32.2 35.7 31.9 30.5 35.9 35.6 ...
```

I normalize the data.

```
means = apply(mydata,2,mean) 
sds = apply(mydata,2,sd)    
nor = scale(mydata,center=means,scale=sds)
```

When i calculate the distance matrix, I can see lot of empty values and moreover distance is measured only from 4 observations.

```
distance =dist(nor) 

> str(distance)
 'dist' num [1:31375] 1.33 2.09 1.9 3.08 3.99 ...
 - attr(*, "Size")= int 251
 - attr(*, "Labels")= chr [1:251] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 - attr(*, "Diag")= logi FALSE
 - attr(*, "Upper")= logi FALSE
 - attr(*, "method")= chr "euclidean"
 - attr(*, "call")= language dist(x = nor)


> distance  # o/p omitted from this post as it has 257 observations.

             1          2          3          4          5          6          7
2    1.3346445                                                                  
3    2.0854437  2.5474796                                                       
4    1.8993458  1.4908813  2.5840752                                            
5    3.0790252  3.4485667  2.2165366  2.7021809                                 
             8          9         10         11         12         13         14
2                                                                               
3                                                                               
4                                                                               
5                                                                               
            15         16         17         18         19         20         21
```

This list goes on empty for the remaining 247 comparisons.

Now, I reduce the data set to 20 observations

Here I  get a proper distance matrix.

```
distancetiny=dist(nor)

> str(distancetiny)
 'dist' num [1:1176] 1.14 1.8 1.61 2.62 3.39 ...
 - attr(*, "Size")= int 49
 - attr(*, "Labels")= chr [1:49] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 - attr(*, "Diag")= logi FALSE
 - attr(*, "Upper")= logi FALSE
 - attr(*, "method")= chr "euclidean"
 - attr(*, "call")= language dist(x = nor)

> distancetiny
            1          2          3          4          5          6          7
2   1.1380433                                                                  
3   1.7990293  2.2088928                                                       
4   1.6064118  1.2871522  2.2483586                                            
5   2.6235853  2.9669283  1.9132224  2.3256624                                 
6   3.3898119  3.3730508  3.3718447  2.2615557  2.0094434                      
7   1.8947704  2.0065514  1.7685604  1.1065940  1.7387938  2.2321156           
8   1.1732465  1.0663217  1.6733689  0.8873140  2.1959298  2.7939555  1.1448269
9   2.2721969  2.0545882  3.4263262  1.4058375  3.1811955  2.4011074  2.3078714
10  2.3753110  2.2424464  3.0289947  1.2808398  2.3230202  1.4242653  1.8571654
11  1.5620472  1.1878554  2.5750350  0.5718248  2.7714795  2.6314286  1.5132365
12  3.5088571  3.2484020  4.1164488  2.2723772  3.1377318  1.4795230  2.8274818
13  2.1448841  2.2679705  1.8726670  1.3494988  1.2176727  1.5544030  1.0725518
14  3.6679035  3.7459402  3.6869023  2.6677308  2.1318420  0.7347359  2.5729973
15  2.9908457  3.3312661  3.1289870  2.4340473  1.8027070  1.3626019  2.3795360
16  1.6117570  2.0283356  1.2011116  1.5961064  1.3196981  2.4456436  1.2569683
17  3.2991393  3.5991747  3.0438049  2.6066933  1.4742664  1.0945621  2.2214101
18  3.9409008  4.0726826  4.0113908  2.9250144  2.5228901  0.9087254  2.8158563
19  2.7468511  2.9495031  3.2439229  1.8312508  2.4122436  1.3932604  1.9640170
20  3.7515064  3.7021743  3.9404231  2.5813440  2.5390519  0.8352961  2.6530503
21  2.3102053  2.3878491  2.0836800  1.4328028  1.2991221  1.5287862  1.1769205
```

There is no empty values in the output when the observation is 21.

Why is this so? Does the dist() do not work when the observation count goes beyond a threshold ?

I'm unable to figure it out. Please help.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: your output for `distance` looks ok to me. note that by default dist object only prints lower triangle of the matrix (leaves upper blank)--see `?dist` (arg 'upper'). if you look look closely at the object you printed, the blanks are all in the upper tri.

Comment: Not really. Please look at 'distance', not 'distancetiny' (which is proper). For 'distance', from the rows 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14.... til 251 are missing. its blank

Comment: First, you only need nor = scale(mydata) since the default is to use the column means and standard deviations. There are multiple distance functions in R and they have multiple arguments so there is no way to help you without sufficient information. What code did you use to create the distance matrix? What does str(distance) show you?

Comment: @dcarlson Thanks for looking into this. I have added the dist commands as well as the str(distance) outputs.

Comment: @Salih your output for `distance` only shows columns 1-21 of rows 1-4 of the distance matrix. Within that region of a matrix made by `dist()` with `upper = FALSE` (the default), the output you printed in the question correctly displays values for the lower triangle of the distance matrix (and no values for the upper triangle). Please expand the printed output to actually show the problem.

Comment: @ChrisHolbrook  But I didnt select any specific region? why is it With the same default settings how is `distancetiny` giving output for all columns and rows ? You can see it works perfect ( a 21X21 matrix lower triangle, although I couldn't paste the entire o/p ) But for `distance` it gives 4x251 matrix. What could be the reason.

Comment: My suspicion is that the data are fine (i.e. `dist()` is operating correctly and your resulting matrix is correct) but that what you are seeing is simply truncated output. Are you using RStudio? When you print `distance` to the console, after your 4th row, do you see something like `[ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 246 rows ]`? If so, that's telling you that the other 246 rows are simply not being displayed/printed because RStudio has some default print option that will limit what is displayed.

Comment: Note that `dist()` produces an object of class `dist`, not a distance matrix. According to `?dist` it returns a numeric vector containing the values in the lower triangle of the distance matrix and some attributes (Size, Labels, Diag, Upper...) that determine how the distance matrix is displayed when printed to the screen/console. Functions that receive a dist object as input know how to correctly interpret this, but if you just want to see the full distance matrix yourself, then you may want to coerce to matrix (`dm <- as.matrix(distance)`) and then either write to disk or `View(dm)`.

Comment: There are some simple things you can do to check the data and the distance matrix. First use summary(mydata). It will show you the mean and quantiles and tell you if you have any missing values in your data.

Comment: Your str(distance) command showed that there are 1176 values. Try sum(is.na(distance)) to see if any of the distance values are missing. There should not be any if there are no missing values in mydata. Then try sum(distance==0) to see if any distance values are 0. If not, then you have a complete distance matrix that is just too large to print to the console without changing the default values. You can also try quantile(distance) to get the quantiles for the distances and hist(distance) to show their distribution. Both of these should show you that you have a complete distance matrix.

Comment: I checked the 'sum(is.na(distance))` and `(distance==0)` and there are no NULL or 0 values. looks like it cripples when trying to print a matrix beyond a certain size

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a size issue. When the dataset contains more than 60-80 observations, the distance matrix is unable to be displayed properly (even for the initial rows). Looks like the values are present in it perfectly alright, and just that we cannot see them as it is. 
Further operation on the distance matrix (like Hierarchical agglomerative clustering ) proved that nothing to worried about it's weird display.

Comment: Limiting printed output is a feature of some IDEs; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758727/how-to-increase-the-limit-for-max-print-in-r