# How can I copy the results (with the omitted rows) of my linear model to any text program?

Tags: r, dataframe, linear-regression

This is the code I wrote:

```
lm_model109 <- lm(1 ~ (2+ 3+ 4 +5) * 6 * log(7) * log(8))
```

(for the information: 2,3,4,5 are factorial variables with a lot of factor levels and and 6,7,8 are numeric variables)

```
summary(lm_model109)

[ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 2072 rows ]
```

How can I copy the results (with the omitted rows) of my linear model to any text program?

Comment: To send R output to a text file instead of the console you can use `sink()`.  But perhaps you wanted something else except all of the model summary in a text file.  Also, having thousands of rows in a linear model output suggests something is wrong.

Comment: @GeorgeSavva why does it mean that there is something wrong? we work with a lot of interaction terms! for your information: 2,3,4,5 are factorial variables with a lot of factor levels and and 6,7,8 are numeric variables. Moreover if I use the sink function it still gives me: [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 2072 rows ] in the text document

Comment: Fair enough if you are sure your model is correct.  You can use `options` to increase the maximum number of rows to print. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758727/how-to-increase-the-limit-for-max-print-in-r

Comment: @GeorgeSavva do you know the answer on my last question?

Comment: It is explained in the answer to the question I linked.

Comment: @GeorgeSavva not this question, another question I posted

Comment: i've answered it